# Solr Indexing Time of Documents

Tags: indexing, solr

is there a way to see the total index time of documents in a collection?
I have looked at this link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api18[1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api18) and especially for the collection stats api, but I did not found any relevant fields. Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: A request to index documents will return the time it took in the response. Look for {"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":5}. Is that what you're looking for? There is no single value that keeps the total time spent indexing over the lifetime of a collection, as far as I know.

Comment: Does this value represent the time for the whole operation, in particular: indexing_time + request_time + response_time or really the only indexing_time? If latter, this would be really fine.

Comment: It only measures the time from when the SolrRequest object is created internally to when Solr is done doing stuff (so the response time to the client isn't included). It does contain some internal overhead, but nothing that should be affected by the client making the request.

Comment: thank you thats what I have needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request to index documents will return the time it took in the response. Look for {"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":5}. There is no single value that keeps the total time spent indexing over the lifetime of a collection, as far as I know. From Shalin's post on [solr-user](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/What-is-QTime-a-measure-of-td495772.html):

> QTime is the elapsed time (in milliseconds) between the arrival of the 
>   request (when the SolrQueryRequest object is created) and the completion of 
>   the request handler. In other words, it will tell you how long it took to 
>   execute your query including things like query parsing, the actual search, 
>   faceting etc.